# How to send message to jboss-7 from jboss-5

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

There are two applications.Earlier both the applications were running in jboss-5. Now one of them is going to get migrated to jboss7

Both the applications communicate with each other via JMS queues . From basic research I understand that we need to access the hornetq in jboss-7 by providing the URL the below way

```
private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "remote://localhost:4447";
```

Also i understand that in jboss-7 we need to access the queues with username and password ie, `SECURITY_PRINCIPAL`

But as far as I know these things cannot be achieved in jboss-5 . Please tell me, is there anyway I can send messages to the queue residing in jboss-7, from jboss-5 ??